# Web page gets unacceptably laggy with Developer Console open

Tags: bug, design, user-experience, april-fools, time-machine

[image]

Without Dev console open, the firework appears at a rate of roughly 1 per frame. With F12 open...

BOOM.

I'm on 8th-gen Intel Core i7 (6 cores, 12 threads) and integrated graphics, the specs shouldn't be too bad to run this effect.

Ideas? Maybe it's because I'm running on Google Chrome? (Chromium kernel?)

Comment: That is not a site bug. When you run with the debugger enabled, execution tends to slow down. Time machines require a lot of resources.

Comment: @CodyGray No. Fireworks appear at every pixel moved with F12 open, rather than up to 1 (or 2) per frame.

Comment: Using Firefox Nightly 68.0a1, Intel® Core™ i7-4712MQ CPU @ 2.30GHz × 8, it’s not laggy.

Comment: Reproduced with Chromium on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments, the problem only seems to appear in Chrome-based browsers.

To solve your issues, uninstall Chrome and install Firefox.

Comment: Or just use IE, like everyone did in the ‘90s.